# DOM node "display" style variable pointer doesn't update styles

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner and I've created an event listener here, that works:

```
var inpt = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(inpt.style.display === 'none'){
    inpt.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    inpt.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

but when I assign the value of 'inpt.style.display' to a variable and try again, it doesn't work:

```
var inpt = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
 var disp = inpt.style.display;
 if(disp === 'none'){
   disp = 'block';
 } else {
   disp = 'none';
 }
});
```

Why doesn't this work? Thank you!

Comment: why don't you use `document.querySelector` ? particular reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not set the the `style` for the `display` property but you are simply setting a new value for your variable `disp`...

`disp` is a variable pointing to a primitive's value, meaning it does not know that is is "connected" to `inpt.style.display`, so when you change `disp` variable, it will never affect `inpt.style.display`.

It could have only affect it, if it was pointing to an Object, for example:

```
var disp = inpt.style; // style is an Object which has the "display" property
```

You **must** directly change the `display` property:

```
inpt.style.display = 'block';
```

and so on.

---

### Try this:

```
var inpt = document.querySelector('input'); // changed to "querySelector"

plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    inpt.style.display = inpt.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

That variable is a string, therefore when you create a new variable, you just get a copy of a string and don't override the old value. Try this:

```
var a = "123"
var b = a;
var b = "something else"
```

Now check the values of b and a. You will see that a hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're copying the value in inpt.style.display. It's a value, not a reference. Reassigning it will not change the original value.

```js
let testObject = { testField: "hello" };
let testField = testObject.testField;
testField = "goodbye";
console.log(testObject.testField); // "hello"
```

You can find some more information in this answer: [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)